# Operations on few dictionaries based on key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 dictionaries

```
demo1={'1':['a','b','c'],'2':['x','y'],...}
demo2={1:['b','c','e'],2:['x','z','w'],...}
coef={'1':5,'2':6,...}
```

I want output like this

```
output={1:2/5,2:1/6,...}
```

where in output value numerator is number of matching values between demo1 and demo2, and denominator is corresponding value in coef.

ex. for key=1 in demo1 and demo2, 'b' and 'c' match, so numerator is 2, and coef for key=1 is 5

I've tried to do it via for loops, but I'm having too much of them, is there more efficient way?

PS: key in demo1 is string, and in demo2 is int, that doesn't matter what returns in output. Either string or int is fine

Comment: When you mean by:i.e `2/5`,1/6 etc... and  do you actually want division?, or just a string?

Comment: @U9-Forward division. I put it in that way for clarity

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: are the keys in `demo2` ints or strings?

Comment: @James, demo1 is string, demo2 is int. That doesn't matter though for output. It can be either string or int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
demo1={'1':['a','b','c'],'2':['x','y']}
demo2={1:['b','c','e'],2:['x','z','w']}
coef={'1':5,'2':6}
result = {i:sum(c in demo1[i] and c in demo2[int(i)] for c in set(demo1[i]+demo2[int(i)]))/coef[i] for i in demo1}
```

Output:

```
{'1': 0.4, '2': 0.16666666666666666}
```

Comment: but initially demo1 is string and demo2 is int

Comment: @U9-Forward No problem. It does seem to appear that the keys in `demo2` must be integers, however.

Answer (score 3):

Easier:

```
print({k:len([i for i in demo1[k] if i in demo2[int(k)]])/v for k,v in coef.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'1': 0.4, '2': 0.16666666666666666}
```

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks a lot, i am going to also vote for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the values to sets and find the length of the intersections

```
{k:len(set(demo1.get(k)).intersection(demo2.get(int(k))))/v for k,v in coef.items()}
{'1': 0.4, '2': 0.16666666666666666}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
output = {len(set(demo1[i]) & set(demo2[int(i)])) / coef[i] for i in demo1}
```

- `s1 & s2` is the intersection of the sets `s1` and `s2`
- `len(s)` will give you the number of elements in the set `s`

Answer (score 0):

Use the length of the merged sets

```
 d = {k: len(set(demo1[k]) & set(demo2[int(k)]))/v for k, v in coef.items()}
```